# Simple Timer Example but it wont work fine

Tags: java, android

I made a simple timer example but it work as it have to be.
Here is the code

```
public class TimerExample extends Activity {
private Timer timer;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    timer=new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TimerMethod();

        }

    }, 0, 10000);

}

public void TimerMethod()
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi this is piyush", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

a toast have to be appeared after 10 sec but it wont happen. please suggest the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `run` method of the timers isn't ran in the UI Thread, thus you can do nothing with your UI directly. So, you can wrap the *UI part* with the `runOnUiThread` method:

```
public void TimerMethod() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi this is piyush", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```